# Cache with limited size; If full remove the oldest

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, cache

Here is a class that stores a single value into the limited cache. If cache is full, it will remove the oldest element to make a space for a new value.
I'm using 2 structures to accomplish this because I need a fast lookup. I'm not very confident this is the best approach.
Cache will contain a small amount of data (lets say 1000 elements).

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <queue>

template <class T>
class Cache{

private:
    int _maxSize;
    std::unordered_set<T> _set;
    std::queue<T> _queue;

public:
    explicit Cache(int maxSize) : _maxSize(maxSize){}

    bool add(T value){
        if(_set.find(value) == _set.end()){ // // if not exists in set
            if(_set.size() == _maxSize){ // if set is 'full'
                _set.erase(_queue.front()); // delete the oldest value from the set
                _queue.pop(); // delete oldest value from queue
            }
            _queue.push(value); // push new value into queue
            _set.insert(value);  // insert new value into set
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    int size(){
        return static_cast<int>(_set.size());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

- Naming of data members: I would avoid duplicating the information that carries with the type. Can you think of something more meaningful?
- Unsigned vs. signed integer for handling the size: as the maximum size is passed to the contructor as an `int`, `static_cast<int>(_set.size())` should be safe. However, when it's foreseeable that you'll implement the class template using containers from the standard library (they all use `std::size_t` for their sizes), why not go with `std::size_t` for `Cache`, too?
- Related to the above: always compile with warnings enabled. `clang++ -Wall -pedantic -Wsign-conversion -Wextra -std=c++11` gives me

  > warning: comparison of integers of different signs [...]
  >
  > ```
  > if(_set.size() == _maxSize){ // if set is 'full'
  > ```

  Again, as `_maxSize` is an `int`, this can be considered a non-issue in practice, but it's still somewhat brittle, if you change some implementation details later on.
- You can only instantiate the `Cache` template when `T` mets the standard hash container requirements (i.e., a `std::hash` specialization is available as well as a comparison operator). To make your class template more reusable, consider adding template parameters that can be passed to `std::unordered_set`. If they have sensible defaults, you don't need to specify them most of the time.

  ```
  template <class T, class Hash = std::hash<T>, class EqualTo = std::equal_to<T>>
  class Cache {
      std::unordered_set<T, Hash, EqualTo> _set;
      // ...
  };
  ```
- When caching an object, you save it twice, one in `_queue` and once in `_set`. For small objects, the duplication might be acceptable, but what if `T` is large? Remember that `std::unordered_map` doesn't invalidate iterators/pointers upon insertion and removal of entries. Consider a `std::queue` of iterators into `_set`.
- Passing `T` by value in `bool add(T value)` can be a reasonable choice as long as you `std::move` it when it's used the last time and `T` supports move semantics. In your case:

  ```
  bool add(T value) {
     // ...
     _queue.push(value); // Don't move here
     _set.insert(std::move(value));  // ... but here!
  }
  ```

  You could also consider an overload set `bool add(const T&)` and `bool add(T&&)` instead as `std::vector::push_back` does for example.
- When you worry about performance and you have varying max. cache sizes known at compile time, consider adding a non-type `std::size_t` template parameter to `Cache`. This way, you could specialize on smaller caches to e.g. use `std::vector` instead of `std::unordered_map`, which can be faster due fewer cache (ha!) misses. You need to do some benchmarking first though, and take different `sizeof(T)` into account.
- A last note on performance: `std::unordered_set` was designed as a drop-in replacement for `std::set`. That's why it doesn't invalidate iterators/pointers into an instance, but that's also why it's not the fastest hash set. Of course, make sure to benchmark this properly, but you might want to have a look at some open address hash set, e.g. the one provided by abseil could be an option.